# Synchronous textArea.clear() followed by textArea.setText() does not clear text

Tags: java, textarea, java-11, javafx-11

When a button is clicked, I'd like to clear the textArea, do some work, then print results in the textArea, all in the same method, synchronously.

```
public void resetClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    textArea.clear();
    String result = someSynchronousWork();
    textArea.setText(result);
}
```

What happens is, the textArea is updated, but the clear action is not visible. The work takes several seconds. If I comment out everything except the `textArea.clear()`, it works.

Comment: (1) The graphics won't be redrawn until another [pulse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) occurs, which can't happen until the FX thread has at least returned from the `resetClicked` method. (2) By extension, your GUI will be frozen for the several seconds it takes `someSynchronousWork()` to complete; why don't you want to use a background thread?

Comment: In short, because it's more work, create a task, bind properties... it seems overkill.

Comment: If you want your UI to be responsive then unfortunately you're going to need to use a separate thread. Note you don't necessarily need to use a `Task`; you could use a simple `Runnable` or `Callable` with an `ExecutorService`—just make sure to only access/update the UI on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. I show an example of using `CompletableFuture` in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, JavaFX doesn't render the next frame until a ["pulse"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) occurs. This won't happen when you clear the text, run a long-running task, and then set the text all in one method; the pulse happens after all this occurs which means what gets rendered is the new text. Also, running a several-seconds-long task on the *JavaFX Application Thread* is not a good idea. All blocking and/or long-running tasks should be done on a background thread—otherwise your GUI becomes unresponsive (and your users become unhappy/nervous).

If this task is too simple to use a `Task` for then you could try a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), which may make it easier for you to invoke simple things asynchronously.

```
public void resetClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    event.consume();

    textArea.clear();
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::someSynchronousWork)
            .whenCompleteAsync((result, error) -> {
                if (error != null) {
                     // notify user
                } else {
                    textArea.setText(result);
                }
            }, Platform::runLater);
}
```

Depending on how you want to handle errors, you can do different things. For instance:

```
// can't ever be an error
supplyAsync(this::someSynchronousWork)
        .thenAcceptAsync(textArea::setText, Platform::runLater);

// just want to show "Error" in text area on error
supplyAsync(this::someSynchronousWork)
        .exceptionally(error -> "ERROR")
        .thenAcceptAsync(textArea::setText, Platform::runLater);
```

***Note:** These examples will execute `someSynchronousWork()` using the common `ForkJoinPool`. You can customize this by passing an `Executor` to `supplyAsync`.*

***Note:** You may want to disable some of the UI components (e.g. the button) while the task is running to prevent multiple tasks being launched at once. Enable the UI components when the task completes.*

---

Also, you seem be using the `onMouseClicked` property of the `Button` to process actions. Consider using the `onAction` property instead; an `onAction` handler is notified for more than just mouse clicks (e.g. when the button has focus and <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed).

Comment: I never used this style before. I like it, thanks a bunch!